# Why do *some* mp4 files play normally and other show unreadable static patterns on one ubuntu machine

Tags: video, mp4

All my mp4's are watchable on my desktop Ubuntu 18.04.

But when I transfer them to my laptop Ubuntu 18.04 they show the pattern below.

This is *despite* the fact that when I record mp4 videos locally on the laptop I can then replay them with no problem.

Most confusing of all when I converts them 'from' mp4 'to' mp4 (i.e. same format) this fixes it.  The new output is viewable.

How to fix?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different codecs were used to encode the video than what your laptop can decode on the unwatchable videos; your desktop has hardware support for the codec, whereas your laptop does not. [MP4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) is a container which can hold [many different formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats#Video_formats_supported), i.e., HEVC/MPEG-H Part 2/H.265, MPEG-2 Part 2, MPEG-4 ASP, H.264/MPEG-4 AVC, H.263, VC-1, Dirac, and others.  Anything recorded on the laptop is recorded only with what the laptop supports.

You have already found the solution; re-encoding the video. The other solution is to buy a more powerful laptop, which may not be practical at this time.

Note from OP: I used VLC convert and this did it!

See:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes and actually I was able to "convert" it and the new mp4 works !